# Full test name in .NET unit test

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a unit test in .NET unit test framework:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldNotAssert()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(false);
    }
}
```

When this unit test fails, the output looks like this:

```
 ShouldNotAssert
   Source: MyTestClass.cs line: 14
   Duration: 24 ms

  Message: 
    Assert.IsTrue failed.
```

The issue is that the test name does not contain any information about the context, i.e. about the test class (`MyTestClass`). I know that there are file references etc. but all the CI jobs which executes the unit tests use this `ShouldNotAssert` name which does not identify the real context.

Is there any way to configure this in the framework? Either in the test to generate better name or in the output generator which creates the failure result.

Comment: Can you not just use a different name with more information specific to the class under test?

Comment: See if `TestContext` helps, it has TestName property. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vstsqualitytools/2006/01/09/using-testcontext-in-unit-tests/ ... But why do you need this anyway? Chances are there are better ways to achieve your goal

Comment: @ismatt I could and I do with test name prefix but this is redundant information and also creates long names with the same prefix which are not very handy. So this is exactly that I would like to solve.

Comment: Try a different test framework such as `xUnit`. It may provide a different output that your CI job can use.

Comment: @Sten Petrov Unfortunately TestContext is read only, so I can get out the test name but cannot change it. We have tousand of tests and if one fail I would like to provide more relevant information about it in the error message.

Comment: @TiborTakács what would you like the output to look like? The class, test method name and even line number are shown in your sample output. Assert's methods take a message, which can help by being more specific about the failure mode

Comment: @Sten Petrov You are right, this is good in VS. But the automated jobs uses the testname as output. Whether it is good or not is another question but to be able to support this approach I have to extend the test name.

Comment: You need to take care of how to name your testcase. Depending on your taste you may want to include the mame of the method you test and the test purpose ShouldNotAssert is not very informative.